# What is the command to check the properties of table in sqlite3?

Tags: database, sqlite

I have created a Table and Inserted rows in a SQLite database file.

What will be the command to check the properties of table in sqlite3?

Comment: what properties do you want to check ?

Answer (score 2):

```
.schema tablename
```

http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html